# passing a parameter to modal in bootstrap

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have 2 pages, for example

```
index.html
remote-content.html
```

in Index.html

```
<a class="btn btn-primary" href="/List/remote-content.html" data-controlId="AccountId" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modal" type="button"><i class="fa fa-search"></i></a>
```

How can I access `data-controlId="AccountId"` from `remote-content.html` when modal when loaded?

Answer (score 1):

Using jQuery, you can access `data-` attributes with the `.data()` method on a jQuery object.

Comment: `var controlId = $("a.btn-primary").data("controlId");` But you should add an id to that button and reference it directly.

Answer (score 1):

Can I access this way.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var controlId = $("#button", parent.document).attr("data-controlId");
});
```